# Question about reading addresses/offsets in C++ within a hooked function

Tags: ida, c++, c

I'm a beginner at this and I'm following tutorials but I am kind of stuck.

I found a function that accesses all characters X position in game. I found this using Cheat Engine and here's how it looks:[image]

All these addresses are X positions of characters in game.

I looked up this function in IDA and the functions looks like this:

```
double __thiscall sub_427380(int this)
{
  return *(float *)(this + 80);
}
```

So I managed to hook this function and read the values in C++.

Here's the code:

```
double hookedFunction(int i)
{
    float f = *(float *)(i + 80);
    return originalFunction(i);
}
```

This works but when I try to read values from other offsets that I found using the "Dissect Data/Structures" function in Cheat Engine I'm stuck.

Here's the structure from one of the addresses I found in Cheat Engine:

[image]

When I subtract 80 from the address and I create a new data structure in Cheat Engine it looks like this: [image]

So here's where I need help. How do I read the string at offset 0040 and the 4 bytes at offset 003C in my hooked function.

I tried doing stuff like:

```
DWORD d = *(DWORD *)(i + 0x3C);
```

But whatever I try I can't get the right values.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a C development question, however the answer is offset `0x40` has a pointer to an array of `char`s.

Code should be the following:

```
char* charname = *(char **)(i + 0x40);
```